# WAMP server startup error how can I solve the error?

Tags: wampserver

the configuration file contain a syntax error on line 14: [EParseError] No tray icon was specified. please assign a tary icon by using one of the trayicon* directives in the [config] section

```
 please I need your help to solve this problem
```

Comment: Which version of WAMPServer did you install?

Comment: Just try a reinstall, and make sure you run it as an administrator